# Trouble redefining an array with its values

Tags: python, arrays, merge

Let's say we have an array as follows:

```
x = [4.0,0,0,2.0,0,0]
```

And we also have a bunch of positions (positions represent indexes + 1 (basically indexes starting at 1):

```
unboundedVarsIndex = [3]
```

My objctive is basically to "merge" or "put togheter" the values of x such that in final we have the following:

```
x = [4.0 , 0, 0-2.0, 0, 0]
```

So basically,

```
for index in unboundedVarsIndex:
     x[index-1] = x[index-1] - x[index]
```

But this gives me the following output:

```
x = [4.0 , 0, -2.0, 2.0, 0, 0]
```

Which makes sense, since I did nothing to delete two from the array. I would like find a way to clear 2 from the array and also I would like to make this code work for more than 1 position, i.e., to make it work for example when we have this:

```
len(unboundedVarsIndex) >= 1
```

Take this as example: Let

```
unboundedVarsIndex = [1,2,3]
```

Then, for the same vector x defined in the beggining, I would like to get the following output:

```
x = [4.0 = x[0] - 0 = x[1], x[2] = 0 - 2.0 = x[3], x[4] = 0 - 0 = x[5]]
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

**UPDATE** Answering the comment:
understand I can do that by doing `unboundedVarsIndex.sort(reverse=True)` but still this doesn't give me the output wanted. Let's say I do the following:

```
x = [4,0,0,2,0,0]
unboundedVarsIndex = [1,2,3]
unboundedVarsIndex.sort(reverse=True)
for index in unboundedVarsIndex:
    x.insert(index-1,x[index-1]-x[index])
    del x[index+1]
    del x[index]
print(x)
```

I get the output: `x = [2,0,0]` and this is not what I wanted. Where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: `del x[index]` would remove the extra value.  If you wanted to loop over a list of indexes to merge, you would need to sort the list and process them in descending order - otherwise, lower index removals would invalidate the higher indexes.

Comment: I understand I can do that by doing ` unboundedVarsIndex.sort(reverse=True) ` but still this doesn't give me the output wanted. Let's say I do the following: ` x = [4,0,0,2,0,0]
unboundedVarsIndex = [1,2,3]
unboundedVarsIndex.sort(reverse=True)
for index in unboundedVarsIndex:
    x.insert(index-1,x[index-1]-x[index])
    del x[index+1]
    del x[index]
print(x) `    I get the output: ´x = [2,0,0]´ and this is not what I wanted. Where am I doing a mistake? I will post the edit I mean to make in the OP.

Comment: I have edited the OP with what I meant to answer you. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: "Then, for the same vector x defined in the beggining, I would like to get the following output:" So the rule is that each time a deletion occurs, it impacts all the subsequent replacements?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Basically its like a variable change. Your x3 becomes x3 - x4 and so on... the point is, if you want to varaible change x2 too, Your x3 would become x4 - x5 instead of x3 - x4 and I think this is the step I am missing.

Comment: I think there has been a miscommunication. The goal of iterating in reverse is to avoid having the deletions affect subsequent indexing. You, however, apparently *want* that effect. So just iterate normally. Also, instead of inserting a value and then erasing two, it would be easier to modify one and erase one.

Comment: "Your x3 would become x4 - x5 instead of x3 - x4 and I think this is the step I am missing. " What you want should happen automatically, if you simply iterate in ascending order over `unboundedVarsIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own issue using the following code:

```
x = [4,0,0,2,0,0]
unboundedVarsIndex = [1,2,3]
unboundedVarsIndex.sort(reverse=True)
for index in unboundedVarsIndex:
    if index-1 in unboundedVarsIndex:
        x[index] = x[index] - x[index+1]
        del x[index+1]
    else:
        x[index-1] = x[index-1] - x[index]
        del x[index]
```

Thanks for all the help in the comments from @jasonharper and @KarlKnetchel. Their help made me realise my mistakes and help me with the syntaxe.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to iterate through some given positions in the array, and for each `position` perform the following:

- Update: `array[position - 1] = array[position - 1] - array[position]`
- Remove: `array.pop(position)`

```
def redefine(arr, unbounded_var_positions):
    for position in unbounded_var_positions:
        if not arr:
            return
        redefine_index = position - 1
        if (redefine_index >= 0) and (redefine_index < len(arr) - 1):
            arr[redefine_index] = arr[redefine_index] - arr[redefine_index + 1]
            arr.pop(redefine_index + 1)
```

Which does the following:

```
>>> arr = [4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
>>> unbounded_var_positions = [1, 2, 3]
>>> redefine(arr, unbounded_var_positions)
>>> arr
[4, -2, 0]
```